# Why NGINX signature could not be verified? The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gpg-signature

I tried

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | sudo -E bash -
```

got error

```
W: GPG error: http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY ABF5BD827BD9BF62
```

I added pub key still get the same

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys ABF5BD827BD9BF62
```

Didn't help also

```
wget https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
--2022-05-10 08:02:28--  https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key
Resolving nginx.org (nginx.org)... 52.58.199.22, 3.125.197.172, 2a05:d014:edb:5702::6, ...
Connecting to nginx.org (nginx.org)|52.58.199.22|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1561 (1.5K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’
```

Why?